How to set up airflow alerting so it alerts only on last retry attempt?
My current DAG looks like:
def download_stage(dag_def: DailyDownloadDefinition, **additional_kwargs):
    ...

    retries = 5
    download = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        python_callable=run_task_ignore_holidays,
        op_args=(download_task, dag_def.parser_code,
                 dag_def.group_name, dag_def.parsing_day_delta),
        op_kwargs={"send_task_kwargs": {"queue": QueuesNames.daily_pass1.value}},
        execution_timeout=dag_def.download_timeout,
        retries=retries,
        retry_delay=dag_def.download_retry_delay,
        on_retry_callback=on_attempted_download_failure_callback, <--- IMPORTANT! 
        **additional_kwargs
    )

    return download



def on_attempted_download_failure_callback(context):
    """
    The callback will issue slack messages and phone calls if current time
    is beyond a tolerance threshold while downloads are still failing.
    """
    tolerance = get_downloads_tolerance()

    # The DAG starts running one schedule interval after its execution date
    # so the timestamp to compare to is the next execution date if we want a
    # threshold of N hours since the DAG started running.
    now_utc = pendulum.now("UTC")
    if now_utc - context['next_execution_date'] > timedelta(hours=tolerance):
        issue_alerts(context)

The above alerts when a download first fails. However I am trying to get it to alert on the last retry failure.
Is this possible?

You can do something like this in the callback function:
task_instance = context['task_instance']
max_retries = task_instance.max_tries
current_try_number = task_instance.try_number
# If last retry:
    # Your implementation

